# How to get specific fields in the List

Tags: mongodb, scala

I have this code to get mongodb data using scala :

```
var user = User.findOneById(userId)
var userGroups = user.get.groups.filter(_.status == UserStatus.ACTIVE)
```

Now in userGroups List I only need **groupIds**, How can I do that?

My Collection

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("53bbb6579b82a1962039449"),
   "_t": "models.User",
   "email": "xxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
   "password": "xxxxx",
   "firstName": "monn",
   "lastName": "ria",
   "status": "Active",
   "receiveAlertsFlag": false,
   "created": ISODate("2014-07-08T09: 13: 59.572Z"),
   "updated": ISODate("2014-07-08T09: 13: 59.572Z"),
   "currentGroupId": ObjectId("507f191e810c19729de860ea"),
   "groups": {
     "0": {
       "_t": "models.UserGroup",
       "groupId"▼: ObjectId("53901c14655cf4a2a6b97c4eadee"),
       "name": "My Group",
       "status": "Active" 
    },
     "1": {
       "_t": "models.UserGroup",
       "groupId": ObjectId("53bbb6579b82a1962f780361eewr"),
       "name": "My Team2",
       "status": "Active" 
    }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like :

```
var userGroups = user.get.groups.filter(_.status == UserStatus.ACTIVE).get.groupId
```

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: What mongodb driver are you using?

Comment: JSON docs can be used a regular Java/Scala Maps, where field name is a map key and field value is a mapped value (could be yet another map). This makes it trivial to achieve what you need.

Comment: Have a look at the [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/project-fields-from-query-results/) specification.

Comment: you're going to get back an array though - do you want an array of all groupIds or only the ones that are active?

Comment: I'm using "import com.mongodb.casbah.Imports._"

Answer (score 0):

In official Scala driver for mongoDB you do it the same way you would in Java, since Scala driver wraps the Java Driver:

```
BasicDBObject keys = new BasicDBObject();
keys.put("groups.groupId", 1);

DBCursor cursor = users.find(new BasicDBObject(), keys);
```

http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/api/#com.mongodb.casbah.MongoCollection shows multiple find method that are available on collection type object.

Now, because you have an array of groups, you might want to get back only the groupId values of the elements which have active status - in that case you would need to use aggregation framework rather than a simple find with project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Asya. will try this and get back to you :)